# Android wear canvas curved lines

Tags: java, android, canvas, wear-os

I'm working on a watch face for Android Wear (testing it on round display of LG G Watch R first) and I have a question about drawing an hour/minute hand. I want to do it programmaticaly and I want my result look something like this:

[image]

I'm sorry for a bad illustration as I'm not really good in Photoshop. But I want it to be something like an arc in the top part and probably sharp on the bottom part. I've never done anything serious with `Canvas` so I don't know what to do at all. I would be very greatful if someone could post a piece of code on how to do that.

P.S. I understand that I need to use the `drawArc()` method but I would like to know if there are any other ways

**Update**: I'm thinking about drawing the hand as a hyperbole. So that for every x it will draw a new arc. Is it a viable solution for the "arc" part?